# Keep MySQL files as 'per-project'?

Tags: mysql, svn

Currently I work at two places - at work and at home. I have a problem with keeping up to date. With files I solved my problem (I use private SVN and commit from phpStorm), but I still have no idea about MySQL. Currently, I just export my tables when I'm going out, but it isn't much of a good way (I know myself, sooner or later I'll forget to do it).

My question is: can I store MySQL data files on per-project basis, so I could commit it into SVN along with other files?

Comment: Can you not just connect to the MySQL instance remotely?

Comment: I work on localhost most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a post commit hook that dumps the database, and a hook before update the inserts the dump.

Comment: You mean running `cmd` before the commit? This actually could work, I just had to write some additional script in PhpStorm. Thanks! But still, I'm open to suggestions ;)

Comment: https://mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101 has some info on how to do this if needed. Though it's for emails, you'll see how to make a script that auto runs on commits.